# Google Dialogflow is not detecting all the entities in the user entered text

Tags: dialogflow-es

We are trying to implement chatbot using Google dialog flow. Created 2 intents (movies & purchases) as below.

[image]

[image]

And created 2 Entities (Movies & Purchases as below).

[image]

[image]

When I tested it with '**I cannot watch my purchased movie**', it is detecting 'movies' intent and it is detecting only one entity 'movies'. It is not detecting 'purchases' entity even though the word 'purchased' is in the user entered text.

[image]

Can any one please let me know how to make sure that dialog flow detects all the entities present in the user entered text and also why it is detecting 'movies' intent as 'purchases' intent also have the training phrases that can match the user entered text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the image of your conversation in Dialogflow it shows that Dialogflow matched the user phrase to the `movie` intent. In your `movie` intent setup you have setup only 1 parameter,
`movies`. Dialogflow will only recognize one entity because you have setup the intent to only look for 1 entity.

If you want the movie intent to be able to recognize both entities you should add a phrase that contains both a `movies` and a `purchase` intent and make sure both entities are available in the Actions and Parameters section of your intent.

Here is a quick example that detects a gender and an age category entity.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jordi. So I need to add the training phrase and mark the word as entity. Otherwise Dialogflow won't recognize different entity.

Comment: One more question. Why it is detecting 'movies' intent. Why it is not detecting purchases intent?

Comment: I can't say for sure, normally it would be because the movies intent has a example phrase that is very similar to the user input, but in this case there isn't an obvious match. Dialogflow works with AI and AI can work in mysterious ways sometimes. In most cases you can limit these kind of strange cases by adding more phrases so the AI gets better at recognizing the input.